# Is there a way to string these together so they work together at the same time basically?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails application.js I have two javascripts what they do is autopopulate my sign up form. The first one is based off what gets put into my emp_id text_field once something is put in there and it matches with what I have in my other table it will pull the user's first name and person_id and place them in the appropriate text_fields. Now I have a my second javascript that looks at the data in person_id text_field because now from the first javascript it has data in it But, the only way to get this second one to work is if I change a number and hit tab then it will fill in my manager_first_name text_field ...Is there a way to have the first javascript pull the initial data then the second one react to data automatically with out me have to click on it or change person_id text_field?

This is my controller for user these are the methods in my javascipts.

class UserController < ApplicationController

```
 def populate_form
  @visual = Visual.find_by_id(params[:emp_id])
  @emp_first_name = @visual.first_name
  @person_id = @visual.pds_alias

    render :json => {

        :emp_first_name => @emp_first_name,
        :person_id => @person_id

    }

  end

  def populate_manager
    @manager = Manager.find_by_person_id(params[:person_id])
    @mgr_first_name = @manager.mgr_name

     render :json => {

        :mgr_first_name => @mgr_first_name
     }

   end
 end
```

Here is my view

```
<div class='row form-group'>
   <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
    <%= f.text_field :emp_id, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_id', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class='row form-group'>
  <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
    <%= f.text_field :emp_first_name, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_first_name', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
   </div>
 </div>



 <div class='row form-group'>
  <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
    <%= f.text_field :person_id, tabindex: 1, id: 'person_id', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
   </div>
 </div>



 <div class='row form-group'>
  <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
    <%= f.text_field :mgr_first_name, tabindex: 1, id: 'mgr_first_name', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And here is my App.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#emp_id').change(function() {
         var url = "/user/populate_form?emp_id="+$(this).val();
         $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           if(!(data.emp_first_name === undefined))
           $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);
           if(!(data.person_id === undefined))
           $('#person_id').val(data.person_id);
         });
       }
     );
   });

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#person_id').click(function() {
         var url = "/user/populate_manager?person_id="+$(this).val();
         $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           if(!(data.mgr_first_name === undefined))
           $('#mgr_first_name').val(data.mgr_first_name);
         });
       }
     );
   });
```

Comment: Tl:dr but can't you just call function 2 at the end of function 1?

Comment: How would I do that could you show me? @Max Williams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (Assuming that you have data as object but not array, Even if you do, you can use Enumerable), You don't have to use Javascript Ajax for this,

```
def populate_form
  @visual = Visual.find_by_id(params[:emp_id])
  @emp_first_name = @visual.first_name
  @person_id = @visual.pds_alias
  @manager_name = Manager.find_by_person_id(@person_id).mgr_name

    render :json => {

        :emp_first_name => @emp_first_name,
        :person_id => @person_id,
        :mgr_first_name => @manager_name

    }
 end
```

Comment: I tried that but its seeing the person_id field as null..   Manager Load (40.6ms)  SELECT  "EMP_DIRECT".* FROM "EMP_DIRECT"  WHERE "EMP_DIRECT"."PERSON_ID" IS NULL AND ROWNUM <= 1
@Ronak Jain